# $End_A(M)$ for representation-finite $A$ and indecomposable $M$

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Given a representation-finite finite dimensional algebra $A$ and an indecomposable module $M$.

> Question: What possible algebras can occur as $End_A(M)$?

Note than when $End_A(M)$ is selfinjective, then $End_A(M) \cong K[x]/(x^n)$.
This suggests that also in general there might not be many more possibilities for $End_A(M)$.

Further questions:

> What algebras can occur as $End_A(M)$ when $A$ has finite global dimension. Is there an example where something different than $K[x]/(x^n)$ occurs?
>
> $End_A(M)$ is a local algebra. Is there a bound on the number of loops it can have? I found an example with 3 loops (which is especially a wild algebra). I would be surprised to see an example with more than 3 loops.

Comment: What happens for the quiver algebras of Dynkin type?

Comment: @JohannesHahn They are representation-directed and thus $End_A(M)$ is isomorphic to the field.

Comment: @JohannesHahn It might be interesting to ask the question for representation-finite algebras of finite global dimension. I think I am not aware of an example of an indecomposable module $M$ there with $End_A(M)$ not being isomorphic to $K[x]/x^n$.